# SerenityBDD - How to configure multiple browsers and multiple drivers with individual capabilities in serenity.conf file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have created a serenity-bdd project version 3.7.1 in java. Below is serenity.conf file inside src/test/resources location.

```bash
webdriver {
    driver = "chrome"
}

environments {
    dev {
        pages {
            admin.url = "https://www.dev.localization.com"
        }
    }
    uat {
        pages {
            admin.url = "https://www.uat.localization.com"
        }
    }
}

drivers {
    edge {
        webdriver {
            capabilities {
                browserName = "MicrosoftEdge"
                "ms:edgeOptions" {
                    args = ["--start-maximized", "inprivate"]
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    chrome {
        webdriver {
            capabilities {
                browserName = "chrome"
                "goog:chromeOptions" {
                    args = ["--start-maximized", "incognito"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running below command, edge driver is not launching in maximised and inprivate mode

```bash
gradle clean build reports -DEnvironment=uat -Dwebdriver.driver=edge
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen - serenity.conf is not capable of defining multiple browsers. It is a current known limitation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).